# ¿Cómo paso un BIN(16) a UUID en una query?

Tags: sql, nodejs, phpmyadmin, backend

Estoy trabajando en backend haciendo una consulta a la base de datos con nodejs y el error viene cuando en mi tabla tengo almacenados id's en BIN(16) y mediante una query los quiero traer como UUID que es al fin y al cabo el tipo de dato que necesito.

```
SELECT uuid_from_bin(id) as uuid ,title, director FROM movie
```

El error es el siguiente:

> code: 'ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST',
> errno: 1305,
> sqlState: '42000',
> sqlMessage: 'FUNCTION movies.uuid_from_bin does not exist',
> sql: 'SELECT uuid_from_bin(id) as uuid ,title, director FROM movie'